# Java regex to match double quoted substrings

Tags: java, regex

I want to parse the following string:

```
String text = "\"w1 w\"2\" w3 | w4 w\"5 \"w6 w7\"";
// "w1 w"2" w3 | w4 w"5 "w6 w7"
```

I'm using `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text)`, so what I'm missing here is the proper regex.
The rules are that regex has to:

- isolate any single word
- any substring surrounded by double quotes is a match
- double quotes within a word have to be ignored (I will later replace them with a whitespace).

So the resulting matches should be:

1. w1 w"2
2. w3
3. |
4. w4
5. w"5
6. w6 w7

Whether the double quotes are included or not in the double quotes surrounded substrings is irrelevant (e.g. 1. could be either **w1 w"2** or **"w1 w"2"**).

What I came up with is something like this:

```
"\"(.*)\"|(\\S+)"
```

I also tried many diffent variants of the above regex (including lookbehind/forward) but none is giving me the expected result.

Any idea on how to improve this?

Comment: How is it possible to have a string covered by `" "` having multiple `"`s in it? Won't it directly consider `w1 w` as a word but not `w1 w"2`?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question, but I think you might have a contradictory requirement here: "double quotes within a word have to be ignored". A word in Java regex is defined as `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes), so you can't have a `"` in a word...

Comment: Try `String pat = "\"[^\"]*(?:\\b\"\\b[^\"]*)*\"|\\S+";`

Comment: @procrastinator; @anothernode: you are right about the strict definition of word in Java regex realm, what I meant here is word split in two by '"', which should be still considered as a single (let me pass the definition)... word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`(?:(?<=^")|(?<=\s")).*?(?="(?:\s|$))|(?![\s"])\S+`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO6fAD/5)

**EXPLANATION:**

- `(?:(?<=^")|(?<=\s"))` - Positive Lookbehind to find the position which is preceeded by a `"`. This `"` either needs to be at the start of the string or after a whitespace
- `.*?` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character other than a newline character lazily
- `(?="(?:\s|$))` - Positive lookahead to validate that whatever is matched so far is followed by either a whitespace or there is nothing after the match(`$`).
- `|` - OR (either the above match or the following)
- `(?![\s"])` - Negative lookahead to validate that the position in not followed by either a whitespace or a `"`
- `\S+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a non-whitespace character

Java Code([Generated from here](https://regex101.com/r/hO6fAD/4/codegen?language=java)):

[Run code here to see the output](http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/1003338)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    final String regex = "(?:(?<=^\")|(?<=\\s\")).*?(?=\"(?:\\s|$))|(?![\\s\"])\\S+";
    final String string = "\"w1 w\"2\" w3 | w4 w\"5 \"w6 w7\"";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
        }
    }

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: In the end I used a slight customization of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the job:

```
"(?:[^"]|\b"\b)+"|\S+
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mfwiWvOFL-TcGP8M)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f4w7Rp/1)

---

Note that in Java, because we're using string literals for regexes, a backslash needs to be preceded by another backslash:

```java
String regex = "\"(?:[^\"]|\\b\"\\b)+\"|\\S+";
```

Comment: I think as per the expected output 1 and 6, surrounding double quotes are not needed.

Comment: @Gurman True, but I haven't been able to find a solution ignoring surrounding quotes. This can be easily done in a second phrase though.

Comment: FYI the `"\"(?:[^\"]|\\b\"\\b)+\"|\\S+"` will match the same strings as [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662742/java-regex-to-match-double-quoted-substrings#comment80274537_46662742), but this one will be a bit slower.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True, good point. Well, feel free to add yours as an answer then ;) Have you find a way to ignore surrounding quotes?

Comment: @sp00m It is impossible. Just use a capturing group then, and if it is not null, add to the final String list.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This one seems to ignore them: `(?<=\B")(?:[^"]|\b"\b)+|[^\s"]+\S*`. What do you think about it?

Comment: @sp00m It becomes too fragile, the pattern is based on assumptions, and adding lookarounds for the indentical delimiters might result in unexpected matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Fair point, thanks for sharing your opinion on this :)